# Need to find a sequence $ a_n $ with following properties: $ \sum_{k= 0}^{n}a_k*a_{n-k}=1 $ in context of generating Funtions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Its in the Chapter for generating Functions but i am not sure, what is the purpose of the exercise, it looks completly random to me.  Is there any use in:

$ a_n $ with $ \sum_{k= 0}^{n}a_k*a_{n-k}=1 $ or something like this
$ a_n $ with $ \sum_{k= 0}^{n}a_k*a_{n-k}=2 $ or something like this
$ a_n $ with $ \sum_{k= 0}^{n}a_k*a_{n-k}=3 $

creating such functions? They don not have to hold at the same time. 
So Basically i need  to find 2 sequences: $ a_n$ with properties $\sum_{k= 0}^{n}a_k*a_{n-k}=1 $

example 1:
$$a_k=(1,-1,1,-1,......)$$
$$a_{n-k}=(1,1,1,1,........)$$
The Product:
$$a_k*a_{n-k}=(1,-1,1,-1,........)$$
And the Sum must be 1

example 2
$$(1,1,1,1,......,1,1)$$
$$(0,0,0,0,.......,0,1)$$
The Product:
$$(0,0,0,0,........,0,1)$$

What is the meaning of this exercice? 
update: I think i need to find a product of two generating functions with a result sequence (0,...0,1).

Comment: Please fix the many equal signs after the sums. Also, please make clear what is given, and what is wanted. Shall all equalities hold in the same time?

Comment: Thank you, i was blind.

Comment: Which are the **two** sequences mentioned in "So basically i need..."

Comment: I have added some explanation. The generating Functions can be added and multiply to create others,...its not clear for me, how this exactly works.

Comment: what is the exact statement of your exercise? it seems you are misunderstanding something. Most likely it's asking you to find just one sequence $\{a_n\}_{n>0}$ such that the relation holds for every $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: This is the statement: "Find a sequence $ a_n $ with properties:  $ \sum_{k= 0}^{n}a_k*a_{n-k}=1$, but i am prety sure its in the context of generating functions

Comment: You seem to be somewhat confused about what a sequence is. Each $a_n$ is a number, not an infinite tuple (i.e. a sequence).

Comment: An n-Tupple can be used to represent the coefficients of the generating funtion e.g. (1,1,1,1,1,1....,1) is the n-Tuppe, they are the coefficients of this Function, $A(x)=\sum_{i>= 0}x^{i}=1/{(1-x)}$ Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331058/generating-function-for-the-sequence-1-1-3-3-5-5-7-7-9-9-ldots?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the binomial theorem, we know that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n} x^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}
$$
whence
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=4^n
$$
In particular
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{4^{n-k}}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=1
$$
as desired.

Comment: Okey i get this one. I have looked all proofs up. I can undersandt each parts. Is this only working for 1? What would happen if one change the excersise to : $ a_n $ with $ \sum_{k= 0}^{n}a_k*a_{n-k}=2 $

Comment: You can use $a_n=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

The point of the exercise is that you associate a recurrence with a product of series, and then use this information to obtain an  explicit formula for the sequence of the exercise.

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence with the property that $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k}= 1$ for each $n$. In particular $a_0^2=1$. If $f$ is its ordinary generating function, this means that $$f^2 = \sum_{n\geqslant 0} X^n = 1+X+X^2+\cdots= (1-X)^{-1}$$

so that $f = (1-X)^{-1/2}$ or $f = -(1-X)^{-1/2}$ when $a_0=1$ and $a_0=-1$, respectively. Since

$$(1-X)^{-1/2} = \sum_{n\geqslant 0} \binom{-1/2}{n} X^n,$$

this gives you an explicit formula for $(a_n)$.

Comment: Could you maybe explain it a little more? I new to the generating functions.

Comment: @thetha Can you point out what is unclear?

Comment: I think i understand the main purpose of the generating function. I have a sequence for which i need to create a closed formula. The coefficient of the sequence could be generated via function if there exist a series of a function. I could give the sequence of the coefficient directly (1,4,9,16,25,36,....) or a formula $a_n=(n+1)^2$ of like in make case above implicit as an imposed conditon that . I think the $a_n$ is the sequence for the generating function. I was trying to create $a_n$ by hand and then try to create the generating function of of known example. You did it somehow different.

Comment: i am not quite sure , but didnt you lost -1, have a look http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=$$(1-X)%5E%7B-1%2F2%7D+%3D+%5Csum_%7Bn%5Cgeqslant+0%7D+%5Cbinom%7B-1%2F2%7D%7Bn%7D+X%5En,$$